# Unix command to remove newline within a field

Tags: shell, unix, awk

*EDIT:*  Thank you all for answering the question, all the answers work. Stack Overflow indeed has a great community.

Receiving a flat file as a source. In one of the fields, the value is segregated into new lines, but there is a need to break the newline and combine it into a single content.

Ex:
File is as below:

```
PO,MISC,yes,"This
is
an
example"
PO,MISC,yes,"This
is
another
example"
```

In the above ex, the data is being read as 9 lines, but we need the input to be read as a single line, as shown below -

```
PO, MISC, yes, "This is an example"
PO, MISC, yes, "This is another example"
```

Tried via the below syntax but did not succeed. Is there any way to achieve this? I also need to print the file contents into another file.

Syntax:

```
awk -v RS='([^,]+\\,){4}[^,]+\n' '{gsub(/\n/,"",RT); print RT}' sample_attachments.csv > test.csv
```

Comment: `tr '\n' ' ' <file`

Comment: hi there, thanks for answering my question. 

there are multiple records in that file. trying this deletes all the new line characters - 

I need to remove all new line characters within quotation marks.

Comment: If you don't REALLY want a blank after every `,` in your output then don't show a blank after every `,` in your expected output, [edit] your question to fix or explain that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With your shown samples Only, please try following `awk`, written and tested in GNU `awk`. Simple explanation would be, setting `RS` to `\"\n` and setting field separator as `,`. In main block Globally substituting new lines with spaces in $NF. Then using `printf` printing current line along with value of `RT`.

```
awk -v RS="\"\n"  'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} {gsub(/\n/," ",$NF);printf("%s",$0 RT)}' Input_file
```

Comment: I think this won't print commas in output. Please check

Answer (score 2):

```
awk -F"," '
   BEGIN{ getline; n=NF; print}
   { split($0,a,FS); 
     while(length(a)<=n){ 
       s=$0; 
       getline; 
       $0=s " " $0; 
       split($0,a,FS); 
     } 
     print $0 }' sample_attachements.txt
```

- `BEGIN(....)` store the number of fields in the variable `n`
- while the number of fields (length of array `a`) is unequal n, read another line, and append it to the input.
- `print $0` finally print the (modified)input line

Answer (score 2):

You may use this `gnu-awk` solution:

```bash
awk -v RS='"[^"]*"' '{ORS = gensub(/\n/, " ", "g", RT)} 1' file

field1, field2, field3, field4
PO,MISC,yes,"This is an example"
PO,MISC,no,"This is  another example"
```

Where input file is this:

```bash
cat file
field1, field2, field3, field4
PO,MISC,yes,"This
is
an
example"
PO,MISC,no,"This
is
another
example"
```

For the updated question use this `awk`:

```bash
awk -F, -v OFS=", " -v RS='"[^"]*"|\n' '{
   ORS = gensub(/\n(.)/, " \\1", "g", RT)
   $1 = $1
} 1' file

field1,  field2,  field3,  field4
PO, MISC, yes, "This is an example"
PO, MISC, no, "This is  another example"
```

Comment: Hi There, 
thanks for answering my question. 

when I print this into another file, the file shows blank. There are actually no headers in the source file. 

I used the unix cmd something like this
awk -v RS='"[^"]*"' '{ORS = gensub(/\n/, " ", "g", print RT)} 1' /pat/sample_attachment.csv > /path/test.csv

Comment: For me `awk -v RS='"[^"]*"' '{ORS = gensub(/\n/, " ", "g", RT)} 1' file > output` is working fine and showing all the output.

Comment: Here is working demo: https://ideone.com/WnlA3A

Comment: Hi anubava, the update logic throws errors in putty. Is that not executable in putty?

Comment: putty is just a terminal emulator. What is your awk version and what error are you getting?

Comment: I have put the cmd in a shell script and tried to execute the same to write it into another file. But the file has 0kb data. 

This is the cmd i have added 
awk -v RS='"[^"]*"' '{ORS = gensub(/\n/, " ", "g", RT)} 1' random_path/sample_file > test.csv

The test.csv file is empty.

Comment: I asked you to check awk version using  `awk --version` command.

Comment: GNU Awk 4.0.2 is the AWK version

Comment: Anubhava, thanks for your input. There was a miss at my end , and now it works fine.

Comment: But just out of curiosity which awk you ended up using finally? I thought [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73775888/548225) worked for you.

Answer (score 2):

I would harness GNU `AWK` for this task following way, let `file.txt` content be

```
field1, field2, field3, field4
PO,MISC,yes,"This
is
an
example"
```

then

```
awk 'BEGIN{RS="";FPAT=".";OFS=""}{for(i=1;i<=NF;i+=1){cnt+=($i=="\"");if($i=="\n"&&cnt%2){$i=" "}};print}' file.txt
```

gives output

```
field1, field2, field3, field4
PO,MISC,yes,"This is an example"
```

**Assumptions**: there is never more than 1 newline in succession, `"` are never nested, Explanation: I inform GNU `AWK` to enter paragraph more, that is treat everything between blank lines as one row and that field pattern is `.`, i.e. every character is field and that output field separator is empty string. Then I iterate over characters, if I encounter `"` I increase `cnt` by 1, which is used for dead-reckoning if I am *outside* `"`...`"` or *inside* `"`...`"`, when I encounter newline character and cnt is odd I am *inside* so I swap that for space character. After all character are processed I `print` them.

*(tested in gawk 4.2.1)*

Answer (score 2):

Using any awk:

```
$ awk -v RS='"' -v ORS= '!(NR%2){gsub(/\n/,OFS); $0="\"" $0 "\""} 1' file
PO,MISC,yes,"This is an example"
PO,MISC,yes,"This is another example"
```

For anything else, see [whats-the-most-robust-way-to-efficiently-parse-csv-using-awk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45420535/whats-the-most-robust-way-to-efficiently-parse-csv-using-awk).

Answer (score 1):

Your input file name is assumed to be "file" here, and output is "newfile."

```
#!/bin/sh -x

cp file stack
cat > ed1 <<EOF
1,4w f1
1,4d
wq
EOF

next () {
[[ -s stack ]] && main
end
}

main () {
ed -s stack < ed1
cat f1 | tr '\n' ' ' >> newfile
next
}

end () {
rm -v ./ed1
rm -v ./f1
rm -v ./stack
}

next
```

Answer (score 1):

If `sed` is allowed, then

```
sed ':a
     /^[^"]*\("[^"]*"[^"]*\)*$/b
     N
     s/\n/ /
     ba
' file
```